# Need help understading prime notation for vector/time series

Tags: notation, index-notation

I have vector/time series with ' symbol at the end:

X=(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>)'

What does it mean? It is derivative of vector/time series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely means transpose.

That is $X$ is a column vector. A clearer notation would be $x=(x_1, x_2 , \ldots, x_n)^T$

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Just one quick question: so all vectors without ' are row vectors? Or they have no dimensions like in R?

Comment: if you write it in row form, I would take it as a row. I tend to interpret vectors as columns. It is context dependent, it's more of a convention thing.

Comment: Thank you again. So I understand when column vectors are specified all non-specified should be taken as row vectors.